# Не распознается голос в speech_recognition

Tags: python, распознавание-речи

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone(device_index=20) as source:
    print("Скажите что-нибудь ...")
    audio = r.listen(source)

query = r.recognize_sphinx(audio, language="ru-RU")
print(f"Вы сказали: {query.lower()}")
```